# reference is not valid VBA hyperlink creation

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a hyperlink that references a previously used variable. The link is linked to a job number that a user can click on to verify job information prior to printing out the worksheet. I am using variables and I am unsure if that is causing the issue or if the whole thing is fudged.

This is my first time attempting something along these lines, so the possibilities could be endless.

Here is the piece of code I am having trouble with. The error i receive is "Invalid Procedure call or argument"

```
       With POSheet

        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("j11"), _
        Address:="", _
        SubAddress:=shtJob.Name, _
        ScreenTip:="Job Sheet", _
        TextToDisplay:="Job Information"

        End With
```

I can post more code if necessary.

Comment: Try `Range("j11")` as opposed to `Cells("j11")`.

Comment: I did and now I am getting a "type mismatch" error.

Comment: That is likely with your address, the `.Range()` is the correct syntax for `Anchor`. What is `shtJob`?

Comment: shtJob is a variable for a job number that the user inputs. The job number is its own worksheet in the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below. You will need to set the `SubAdress` property to hyperlink to the current workbook. Note that the string must look like `"Sheet1!A1"` if you want the hyperlink to go to Sheet1 cell A1.

```
   With POSheet

    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("j11"), _
    Address:="", _
    SubAddress:=shtJob.Name & "!A1", _
    ScreenTip:="Job Sheet", _
    TextToDisplay:="Job Information"

    End With
```

Comment: That tells me it is an invalid procedure or call argument

Comment: Is `shtJob` a string variable? And can you run the procedure and when you get the error type `Debug.Print shtJob` in the immediate window. The same procedure works for me, but I know the value of the variable I pass.

Comment: No, it isn't. it is used as a worksheet. Is there a way to convert it into a string? I know it may be a dumb question, but I am not so good at this.

Comment: No problem. See my edit. If that does not work, use `shtJob.Name & "!A1"`.

Comment: It creates the hyperlink now, however i now get a "reference is not valid" message

Comment: Even using `shtJob.Name & "!A1"`? I've edited my example above to reflect this now.